# Bootstrap panels won't collapse completely

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.1 (bootstrap.min.css file).

As stated in the title, I am using bootstrap's collapsible panels to hide/show customer details. Something is happening when generating the page however that causes some of the tabs to not collapse all the way.

Here is what it looks like collapsed...
[image: Example of not collapsed panels]

And here is what it looks like extended...
[image: Example of collapsed panels]

I use a panel counter variable that gets incremented every time a new panel is created (1142/1138: 'name') to make sure only two panels are on a row, and they stay together even through filters.

```js
if (panel_counter % 2 === 0) {
  html += '</div><div class="row">';
}
```

Eventually html is appended to a div with `id="panel-results"`. How can I stop this overflow?

[Here is](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzvh1dbt/2/) some of my JavaScript and HTML. The JavaScript is very long, but I included (what I think) is necessary.

The class names of `gateway...` are used only for sorting and determining their color.

Comment: looks like there is some extra padding or margin. do u have your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Yeah, can you post the rest of the code you are using? html and css?

Comment: Added jsfiddle, let me know if I need to add more JavaScript. It is very long.

Comment: @PhilipCorneliusGlover you missed out the CSS...

Comment: @evolutionxbox Updated link